# Type.IsAssignableFrom not working with Predicate<>

Tags: c#, generics

The following snippet, I believe should work but fails. I've also tried IsInstanceOfType as well.

```
Assert.IsTrue(typeof(Predicate<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Predicate<int>)), "No predicate match!");
```

Is my assert wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that wouldn't work - you could never have a value of the open type, so that couldn't work.

It sounds like you probably want [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx):

```
if (type.IsGenericType &&
    type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Predicate<>))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Close!  p.GetType().IsGenericType && p.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()==typeof(Predicate<>)

Comment: @DanVallejo: All you need is `Type type = p.GetType()` first :) (There's nothing about `p` in the question - we didn't really know what you were trying to do.)

Comment: sorry, my point was that it is IsGenericType, you originally had IsConstructedGenericType or something like that. Thanks, it pointed me in the right direction :)

Comment: @DanVallejo: IsConstructedGenericType would have worked too (and been a bit more specific) but I hadn't noticed it's for .NET 4.5 only...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how that method is supposed to work.

For the relationship between type `A` and type `B` in:

`A.IsAssignableFrom(B) == true`, `A` is a base class of `B`, or `A` is an interface of `B`

Kind of like:

```
public class Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }
```

So that:

```
typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dog)) == true;

// you can do
Dog spot = new Dog();
Animal a = spot;        // assigned an Animal from a Dog

// but not
Animal b = new Animal();
Dog spike = b;          // compiler complains
```

Comment: A should be a base class of B, otherwise you can never have polymorphism.